# Most Efficient Way to Create a Numpy Array Based on Values in Multiple Cells of Another Array

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an application where I have to process 1000's of 2D arrays.  The result of the processed array is based on half of a Kings Move neighborhood in the original array.  I'm trying to avoid loops if I can due to speed considerations.  So, here is an example Numpy Array:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  5.,  5.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  1.,  5.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  5.,  1.,  1.,  5.,  5.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  1.,  5.,  1.,  1.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  1.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  5.,  1.,  5.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

At each element, I want the sum of the cell right above it, the upper right diagonal element, the cell to the immediate right and the lower diagonal.  So, using the element at [6][0] I would want to sum 1 + 1 + 1 + 5.

Of course, I also have to handle the edge cases where one of the 4 cells is not there.  I have started with the padded zeros on top and far right to manage some of that but I'm stuck right now.  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've suggested a couple of improvements for a similar problem in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/149176/27783; you might also find a lot of `convolve2d` suggestions here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing can be viewed as performing a convolution with a particular convolution kernel.  Here's a solution using the scipy `convolve2d` function:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.signal

x = np.random.randint(5,size=(10,10))

kernel = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]])
kernel = np.fliplr(np.flipud(kernel))

check = sp.signal.convolve2d(x,kernel,mode='same')

print x
print check
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Your approach to create the kernel in the form that I can see where it starts and it's mirror image applied was very helpful in understanding the process.